# Maven - Add dependency to dependency

Tags: maven

Is it possible to enforce a rule like "If X is a dependency, always also include Y as a dependency" in maven? Something like...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <include>
        ... something...
        </include>
    </dependency>
```

Exclusion works fine, but inclusion doesn't seem. Reason is simple, I excluded hamcrest from junit in my dependency management and would like child projects automatically get the hamcrest-all dependency without having to explictly declare it.

Comment: Guess that's not possible. Why don't you want to explicit declare the hamcrest-all dependency? This sounds to me like the easiest solution.

Comment: A dependency automatically adding without declaring does not make sense. If you like to use a dependency than declare it...You could add the dependency in a dependencies (not inside dependencyManagement) and via inheritance it would be...but i can't recommend that.

Comment: @Jan: Makes it less error-prone. I decided to exclude hamcrest-core and instead us hamcrest-all, but this leads to other developers needing to explicitly include both, with I hoped somehow to circument by "replacing" the hamcrest-core with hamcrest-all.